# how to find index of a row in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i fetch column names from a table on index basis, like I want to make a tables whose column name should be the name of last column fields of a result set of a query, but those result sets last columns value may be different at different execution time, so i want to know how can i fetch those index value of that last column to make a temp table with column name of those last columns value of a result set.
Is there any way/function in sql server to dynamically form that?

Comment: He's asking about PIVOT but doesn't know it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sp_helpindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188771.aspx):

> Reports information about the indexes
>   on a table or view.

Answer (score 0):

[You can also use ROW_NUMBER as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)